# terraform returns 'invalid_grant' for GCP when attempting to create load balancer and I cannot view or edit SA permissions as owner

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, google-iam, gcp-load-balancer

I have a brand new GCP account that I'm the only owner of, this is a personal/clean brand new project.

I manage the infrastructure exclusively with terraform and trying to create a HTTPS load balancer to route requests to a fixed ip, which I then want to forward to a bucket where I have a webapp, I've setup this type of infrastructure in the past via the UI but not via terraform.

When attempting to create this piece of infrastructure:

```
resource "google_compute_global_address" "main" {
  name = "main"
}

resource "google_compute_forwarding_rule" "lb" {
  name                  = "lb"
  provider              = google-beta
  region                = "europe-west2"
  project               = "owlee-software"
  ip_protocol           = "TCP"
  load_balancing_scheme = "EXTERNAL_MANAGED"
  port_range            = "443"
  target                = google_compute_global_address.main.address
  network_tier          = "PREMIUM"
}
```

this throws

```
│ Response: {
│   "error": "invalid_grant",
│   "error_description": "Account has been deleted"
│ }
```

for brand new service accounts -- I have deleted the account and created another one -- with another file, if I remove this resource everything gets instantiated fine via the service account in the GCP account. This is the only 'google beta' provider that I have in the project as well.

I'm not sure if this is because of the resource configuration being wrong or something is happening with the service account.

When I try to inspect the service account I just created and made editor on the project, I can't, it shows greyed out with the following text:

```
Could not find an ancestor of the selected project where you have access to view a policy report. On at least one ancestor, you need the following permissions: 

cloudasset.assets.analyzeIamPolicy,

cloudasset.assets.searchAllIamPolicies,

and cloudasset.assets.searchAllResources
```

My single-main account has the following roles attached to it:

```
Cloud Asset Owner
Organization Administrator
Owner
Project IAM Admin
Security Admin
```

I've added all of them after the Owner didn't seem to be enough.

Any suggestions appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 14):

It's an authentication issue. For me what solved was running.

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

Followed by the `terraform apply`

But you can check [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/guides/provider_reference) the documentation on how to authenticate with terraform